# RabbitMQ is crashing when I am trying to send large amount of messages

Tags: node.js, express, rabbitmq

I am using RabbitMQ as a queuing solution in my application. I am using free version of `https://www.cloudamqp.com` which offers a queue size of 10,000 messages. I tested it with 10 messages and it's working fine but when I am trying to send 9,000 messages in a queue it's showing me below error:

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 15.206.75.114:5671
at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1247:16) {
  errno: -111,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '15.206.75.114',
  port: 5671
}
```

Below is my code to send messages in a queue where I am fetching rows from Excel sheet having around 9,000 rows. To read Excel file I am using XLSX library.

```
const express = require('express');
const XLSX = require("xlsx");
const amqp = require('amqplib/callback_api');
require('dotenv').config();

const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3300;
onst file = XLSX.readFile('./limit9.xlsx')

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  const sheets = file.SheetNames;
  for (let i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) {
    const temp = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(
      file.Sheets[file.SheetNames[i]]
    )
    temp.forEach((res) => {
      sendData(res);  //This function will send data to RabbitMQ
    })
   }
});

function sendData(res) {
  amqp.connect(process.env.RABBITMQ_URL, (err, connection) => {
    if (err) {
      throw err;
    } else {
      connection.createChannel((err, channel) => {
        if (err) {
          throw err;
        } else {
          let queu = "review_data";
          channel.assertQueue(queu, {
            durable: false
          });
          var json = JSON.stringify(res);
          channel.sendToQueue(queu, Buffer.from(json));
        }
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Why is the above code working fine for small amount of rows but failing for large number of rows?

Comment: I suggest contacting CloudAMQP support. Or, if you can, examine the RabbitMQ log file at the time your application experiences that error.

Comment: Where can I see log file I am using ubuntu.

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Arabbitmq.com+logging